# jQuery: Submitting a link with $.ajax POST with two variables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have the following three vars:

```
var action,
    pubMode,
    token;
```

All three values should be submitted via POST and with ajax. Since POST doesn't take an url I have absolutely no idea how to do so?

```
function ajaxPost(action, pubMode, token) {

    $.ajax({
        url: ??,
        dataType: "text json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(jsonObject,status) {

            console.log("function() ajaxPost : " + status);

        }
    });
}
```

Can you guys please help me out here! Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has a `data` option where you can pass the variables as on object, or as a query string.

POST is not like GET where you tack the variables onto the URL.  Use the URL you want to post to as `url` and use `data` to send the variables.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://your/url/here',
    dataType: "text json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {action: action, pubMode: pubMode, token: token},
    success: function(jsonObject,status) {

        console.log("function() ajaxPost : " + status);

    }
});
```

Comment: thank you. is it also possible to use the following variable name? `my[pub_mode]: pubMode`. Whenever I use the square brackets the code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @mathiregister: You can do that in 2 ways.  1, use query string notation: `'my[pub_mode]='+pubMode+'&my[action]='+action+'&token='+token`.  2, send it as an object in the object: `{my: {pub_mode: pubMode, action:action}, token: token}`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) parameter to pass it an object:

```
function ajaxPost(action, pubMode, token) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "targetpage.php",
        dataType: "text json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action: action, pubMode: pubMode, token: token},
        success: function(jsonObject,status) {

            console.log("function() ajaxPost : " + status);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is it also possible to use square brackets in the data variables? Like I commented above? `data: { my[pub_mode]: pubMode, token: token }` Because when I use the square brackets I get a syntax error.

Comment: No. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. That part is the name of the POST variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
    url: "YOUR URL",
    data: {action: action, pubMode: pubMode, token: token}
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Don't forget that your URL can contain a combination of get and post parameters.  Pass the get ones through the URL.